# Android default throbber animation (Froyo 2.2)

Tags: android

I'm looking for the location of the Android Froyo (2.2) default throbber animation resource.
(In the progress dialog displayed as a animated wheel spinning).

What is the type of animation?
(gif, png, avi?)

And how to get it as a separate file (or images) to be able to adjust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the type of animation? (gif, png, avi?)

It is a plain PNG file. Animation is probably handled via `RotateAnimation`.

> And how to get it as a separate file

It is in `$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/$VERSION/data/res`, where `$ANDROID_HOME` is wherever you installed your SDK and `$VERSION` is some Android API level (e.g., `android-8`). In there, you will find all of the standard resources. You will find them as `spinner_black_*.png`.

Comment: Great. I found it and indeed the png is a single image which is rotated (seems 30 degrees to right at a time).